# How to validate user session on every page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I'm working on this project in Codeigniter and i created login and register script but I don't know how to validate user on every page.
When user logs in what data to store in session (Ci session user_data), so i can compare it to database on every page to se if the session is valid?
I'm using codeigniter's session class and I'm storing the values automatically in the database. Please help me I'm stuck here...

My session is handled like this :

1. When ever any user reaches my webpage he gets unique hashed (md5) session id that is checked when ever a page is loaded. If it exists do nothing if it doesn't generate a new one. It changes every 5 minutes.
2. When user logs in what data to pass to so i can compare it to the database later on ( on every page load)

I don't know if storing only the 'is_logged' = 1 cookie is safe. I want to check cookies on every server request.

Comment: Note that querying the database on every page load is a significant performance hit. Depending on your needs it might be justified but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon succesful login, you create a

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('authorized' => true));
```

You can then make an auth library, or a model method, whatever suits you that just checks if this session data exists.

```
function is_logged()
{
  return (bool)$this->session->userdata('authorized');
}
```

if FALSE, user is not logged, if TRUE it is. You can call this function on every controller's method you need to place behind authentication, or in controllr's constructor if you need it for all methods (ex. an admin panel)

have a look, for ex., on how Ion Auth, one of the mainstream Auth Libraries in CI, handles the thing (uses the logged_in() method which does the same as in my example code. Keep in mind that sessions are encrypted, and if stored in database security is even higher);
https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/libraries/Ion_auth.php

Comment: theoretically if an local user modifies his cookies and sets 'authorized' = true even if he is not logged it would he be able to log in? Also can local cookies be modified?

Comment: cookies are encripted, that operation should be not so easy. BEsides, you're storing sessions in database, so cookies aren't involved

Comment: so lets say i have an auth() method acting as a __construct class that check session before any other method is called. Am I supposed to check against database to se if an user is logged in (authorize = 1) or against cookies? also could you explain your second sentence more clearly. Thank you

Comment: ok, so to wrap up :
1. In session table i have user's cookies.
2. when user opens a page i check his cookies against cookies in session table
3. if session_id is a match and he is logged_in = 1 (in cookies and in table) then he is ok?

Comment: If you set to use the database, you use the normal method call, CI automatically will check the database, no need to manually querying it. And basically, yes, the work flow is along those lines. If you need more methods, or a source of inspiration, look at long-time tested code: Ion Auth or Tank Auth, for example, the 2 most used (statistics made up by me now) CI's authorization libraries. You can see how hey handle the work, which to the barebone is like I pointed out

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are stored on the server so no validation is required. You only need to validate what you put in the session.

Sessions are authenticated by the user supplying a session_id cookie (`PHPSESSID`).

Cookies on the other do require validation, but cookies shouldn't be used to store critical data so it's a bit moot.

Comment: CI's session are encripted cookies, not the native php $_SESSION array, and OP said he's using CI's session library

Comment: Yes .. he edited his question. My answer applies to PHP's native session handling.

Answer (score 0):

You should have write a function in helper like session_helper.And in constructor of your class call this helper method.If your user is logged in correctly then it will continue,other wise it will redirect to log in page.Your Helper should be like this

```
   function session_set()
   {
$ch=&get_instance();
if($ch->session->userdata('your_session_id')=='')
{
    redirect('your_login_page');

}
```

and in controller you should check like this(constructor)

```
   session_set();
```

Hope this will work for you